# Impact of changes to the CAS policies in .NET 4.0?

Tags: sharepoint, .net-4.0, wss, c#-4.0, cas

As stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2009/05/27/coding-with-security-policy-in-net-4-0-implicit-uses-of-cas-policy.aspx), the way evidence is loaded will change in .NET 4.0. How will this impact systems like SharePoint where you can specify exactly which permission will be granted for a dll in the wsp-package? Isn’t SharePoint using AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(Name,Evidence) internally to make this possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.0 won't be used for SharePoint until the release **after** SharePoint 2010. We will still be on .NET 3.5 until then. So perhaps revisit this issue at a later date.